# visjs icons are not shown in chrome

Tags: javascript, visualization

I'm using using visjs and encountered a mysterious problem where the icons of nodes are not shown when the web page is displayed.
The icons appear only after clicking the area where they are displayed.
Following a jsfiddle (not mine) that reproduce the same problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/adgd87/szt7h6kv/

Here is the code:

```
    var nodeSet = [{
      id: 1,
  shape: 'icon',
  icon: {
    face: 'FontAwesome',
    code: '\uf286',
    size: 40,
    color: '#57169a'
  },
  label: '1: fa-fort-awesome - f286',
}, {
  id: 2,
  shape: 'icon',
  icon: {
    face: 'FontAwesome',
    code: '\uf1d1',
    size: 40,
    color: '#f0a30a'
  },
  label: '2: fa-empire - f1d1'
}];

// create an array with nodes
var nodes = new vis.DataSet(nodeSet);

// create an array with edges
var edges = new vis.DataSet([{
  from: 1,
  to: 2
}, {
  from: 1,
  to: 3
}]);

// create a network
var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');
var data = {
  nodes: nodes,
  edges: edges
};
var options = {
  layout: {
    randomSeed: 2
  },
  edges: {
    arrows: 'to'
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: true
  }
};

var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
```

Thanks for any tips

Comment: Probably the fonts are not loaded yet when the chart is rendered the first time. By the time you click on it the font assets are loaded and the chart can then display it. If you want to solve the issue use a font loader to load the needed assets before creating the chart.

Comment: Great. You gave me a good tip, I didn't think that the reason could be related to the fact that they were not loaded. So using your idea, i used $timeout (angularjs) to delay the build of the graph and now it's working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

What is happening is that the fonts have not been loaded in the page when the drawing starts and, because font icons usually use an Unicode space that is usually filled with no chars, a squared rectangle is shown.
When the font is loaded the drawing engine can repaint with the right font and so you'll see the images appear. Usually drawing engines use a lazy drawing techniques, so click is a simple way to trigger it.

But now the complex question: how to know when the font assets has loaded?
Track the loading process of a font is an extreme complicated task, which is now being addressed by the new [CSS Font Loading W3C spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-font-loading/).

The support of it it's not great yet though, as you can see on the [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=font-loading) page:
[image]

Using a timeout it is not a solution, you're just betting that the timeout will trigger soon after the font has been loaded. This is not true if the user connection is from a mobile device believe me.

This means that you need some helper for this, and luckily a cross-browser helper for this exists, and it is called [WebFontLoader](https://github.com/typekit/webfontload).

What you need to do with it is pre-load the font, then start your vuejs:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.5.10/webfont.js"></script>
 <script>
   WebFont.load({
     custom: {
      families: ['My Font']
     },
     // startYourChart is your function that starts the chart drawing
     // when the font is loaded start to draw the chart
     active: startYourChart,
     // The detection in older browser for FontAwesome doesn't always work
     // so this one makes sure that your chart starts after a loading timeout
     inactive: startYourChart
   });
 </script>
```

In the case you're using Angular there's an handy wrapper for WebFontLoader here: [angular-webfontlaoder](https://github.com/degdigital/angular-webfontloader).
In the `example.html` it shows how to use it:

```
var app = angular.module('TestApp', ['webfont-loader']);
app.controller('TestController', function($scope) {
  $scope.$on('webfontLoader.loaded', function() {
    alert('font loaded!');
  });
});
```

P.S. For more info about how Font Loading works and strategies to optimize it here some interesting pages:

- [Controlling Font Performance with font-display](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/02/font-display?hl=en)
- [Better @font-face with Font Load Events](https://dev.opera.com/articles/better-font-face/)
- [A Comprehensive Guide to Font Loading Strategies](https://www.zachleat.com/web/comprehensive-webfonts/?utm_source=ponyfoo+weekly&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=issue-20)

Comment: Marco, very clear explanation, and I understand your fear about the so bad workaround (using $timeout) I thought implemented. I will go forward with your recommendation, and probably using the angular-webfontloader. Thanks for your time and kindness.

Comment: in my case, i was missing including vis.css